# Ruby 1.9.2 export a CSV string without generating a file

Tags: ruby, csv, ruby-1.9.2

I just can't get the 'To a String' example under 'Writing' [example in the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/classes/CSV.html) to work at all.

ruby -v returns:
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

The example from the documentation I can't working is here:

```
csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << ["row", "of", "CSV", "data"]
    csv << ["another", "row"]
end
```

The error I get is:

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

So it seems like I am missing an argument, in the documentation [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/classes/CSV.html#M000182) it states:

```
This method wraps a String you provide, or an empty default String
```

But when I pass in a empty string, it gives me the following error:

```
No such file or directory -
```

I am not looking to generate a csv file, I just wanted to create a string of csv that I send as text to the user.

Comment: Did you place =>  require 'csv'  <= before your method call?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is code I know works against Ruby 1.9.2 with Rails 3.0.1

```
def export_csv(filename, header, rows)
    require 'csv'

    file = CSV.generate do |csv|
        csv << header if not header.blank?
        rows.map {|row| csv << row}
    end

    send_data file, :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present', :disposition => "attachment;filename=#{filename}.csv"
end
```

Comment: I've gotten errors when using `blank?` before, so I use `empty?`.